# How to retrieve second value from a text?

Tags: javascript, split, getelementsbyname

How could I get the second value out of a text? E.g. AB-10: 1234. I want the function to display 1234 instead of 10.

```
function myfunction(){
var txtNIM = document.getElementsByName("txtNIM")[0].value;
var somArr = txtNIM.split(String.fromCharCode(10));
[...]
} 

<textarea name="txtNIM" cols="70" rows="9">
ABC-10: 1234
CBA-20: 4321
</textarea>
```

Comment: Show us what you are doing with the `somArr`!

Answer (score -1):

There are a few different ways to achieve what you want. If you do not want to use regex and are targeting relatively modern browsers this should work fine:

```
var getSecondValue = function(row) {
    var allRows = document.querySelector("textarea[name='txtNIM']").innerHTML.trim().split("\n");
    var str = allRows[row];
    return str.slice(str.indexOf(':')+1).trim();
}


getSecondValue(1); //4321
```

Comment: If the first is always wanted, why not just use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector), which returns only the first match (or `null`).

Comment: I would rather they add some sort of identifier, class or id, to more easily target the desired textarea. If this is to be implemented for multiple textareas this needs an additional loop to iterate over all selected text areas.

Comment: hehe. thanks. I've spent 2 days trying to get the value after the colon, but i just can't get it to work, even with your help. I think this is beyond my knowledge of javascript. Is there a simpler way to call the value after the colon?

Comment: All you need to do is pass the row that you want the second value for. The rows are zero-based so 0 is the first row and so on. Have you changed anything in your code from what is shown in the post? The code I commented requires that the textarea has a name of 'txtNIM'.